# Import existing address to BIP-32

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, bip

I would like to know if there is a way to import an existing address (not generated through the BIP-32 protocol and not derived to it) to my `BIP-32` master node.

I am using the `bitcoinjs-lib` library on Node.js and `BIP-39` for seed management.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

BIP 32 is not a wallet, it is a method for deriving many keys from a master secret in a deterministic way. There is no way of deriving a specific unrelated private key from a master secret.

Comment: Isn't there another way to use this feature in a non-custodial wallet?

Comment: Some wallets can store individual private keys in addition to BIP 32 derived keys. However this is not a feature of BIP 32 itself.